# Is there a .findUsingParent() function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

`div.tabs` is a container of tab control. `div.tab` is an individual tab, child of `div.tabs`. `div.tab.active` is the tab currently showing.

`.data` is a whatever element. It can appear in any `div.tab`, or just appear in `body` when these is no `.tab`.

Task:

- If there is a `.tabs`, select `.data` that are child of `.tab.active`.
- If there is no `.tabs`, select all `.data`.

I wrote the following two version:

```
    // First version
    var data;
    if ($('.tabs').length) {
        data = $('.tab.active .data');
    } else {
        data = $('.data');
    }
    // Section version
    var data = $('*');
    if ($('.tabs').length) {
        data = data.find('.tab.active');
    }
    data = data.find('.data');
```

But I wonder if there is a function `s.findUsingParent(e)` which **selects elements that are children of `e` from a set of elements `s`**:

```
// Expect
var data = $('data');
if ($('.tabs').length) {
  data = data.findUsingParent('.tab.active');
}
```

*Is there in jQuery?

Is there a pure css solution?*

Comment: Is specified problem just simplified example, or is it actual issue? Your 'First version' seem to be much more efficient solution for it then filtering, and imo more readable.

Comment: @Frax It's almost the original problem. In my intuition the first version is more efficient, but **I'm not sure**. The main reason I asked this question was that I felt the first version isn't DRY enough. If I rename `.data`, I will have to  make changes in two places.

Comment: You may try using ternary operator `?:`, like `data = $(($('.tabs').length ? '.tab.active .data', '.data') `, if repetition of `data` bothers you. On the other hand, I would be more concerned about unnecessary change in `data`'s value (in second version) then that repetition - I find assigning variables only once much clearer than doing that twice or more times - but that's just a personal preference. I would even consider wrapping that in function - `function getData(){ if (...) { return ...; } else { return ...; }}; var data = getData();`, but that seems like a bit overengineered ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` function to filter the element that have parent as `.tab.active`:

```
var data = $('data');
if ($('.tabs').length) {
  data = data.filter(function(){
      return $(this).closest('.tab.active').length !=0;
   });
}
```

Comment: Filter may take selector as it's argument. I would expect `data.filter('.tab.active *')` to be much more efficient, and quite shorter.

Comment: @Frax `data.filter('.tab.active *')` works like a charm